# Flash like website intro with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to do something which would look like a flash intro to a website with jQuery/CSS? I only need to show a black screen with a logo for some seconds before I show the content to the user. I mean, I could try showing only the content of a div, but I don't know how I'd get that div to fit the whole screen... something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(body not(#intro-covering-page)).css("display", "none");
$('#intro-covering-page').delay(2000).fadeOut();
}); /* I still haven't figured how to properly make this work*/
```

and maybe having the  before the main container. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fit the whole screen, although it might look weird if it pops up too late, so you have to make it look good in one way or another.

```
css = {
    'width' : $(window).width(),
    'height' : $(window).height(),
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'background-color' : '#000000'
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(#intro-covering-page).css(css);
    $('#intro-covering-page').delay(2000).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: this covers only the background, for more information the div is the first thing after the body tag

Comment: @la_f0ka. I basically ment the div to be 'absolute', so that it is positioned 0,0 in the browser. For safety add a z-index = 100 or something to make sure that it is on top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Let your css hide `#intro-covering-page`

```
#intro-covering-page {
   display: none;
}
```

Then using js

```
$(function() { // that's short for  .ready()
    $('#intro-covering-page').delay(2000).fadeIn();
});
```

Of course, if we want to be sure about user's js status we do something like that

```
.js #intro-covering-page {
   display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('html').addClass('js');
    $('#intro-covering-page').delay(2000).fadeIn();
});
```